# How to disable application defined via Context element of server.xml in Tomcat?

Tags: tomcat

I have a web application defined via `<Context>` element in my `server.xml` configuration on Tomcat. I need to be able to automatically disable this application under certain conditions. The change should be effective after tomcat restart or sooner.

Is there some configuration switch that I could use for that purpose? I don't want to completely remove or comment out the `Context` node because it would add complexity to restoring the application (also done automatically under certain conditions).

I tried `deployIgnore` attribute of `Host` element, but it only work for applications that are deployed by copying a war into webapps directory. Application defined via `Context` is not affected.

I'm using Tomcat 7, if it makes any difference.

Answer (score 0):

Could you use the Tomcat Manager App to do this? You can make a web request to stop an app:

```
http://localhost:8080/manager/text/stop?path=/your_app
```

And then start the app in a similar way:

```
http://localhost:8080/manager/text/start?path=/your_app
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer. It's good approach for manual managing web applications on development environment. However manager application is usually removed in production environment (at least we do it that way), so this approach doesn't work for me.